# Difference between "Pilot" Testing and "Beta" Testing?

Tags: manual-testing, terminology

I was asked this in an interview. I knew about Alpha/Beta release testing , but had no idea about Pilot testing in Software Engineering.

Please explain in details with real life examples.

Comment: Have you also pondered on the auto pilot testing??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pilot testing is when a select group of end users try the system under test, before deployment, to provide feedback about the product.

Limited users use the product in pilot testing, and product is installed at the end customer to validate once the product is ready for the production in beta testing.

Beta testing is done at the client side (last stages of development cycle) and all end users use the system and see whether the system is working as per their given requirements.

This is done after pilot testing is successful and the defects found in case of pilot testing are fixed.

**PS: This question would be having a million Google results since it is one of most basic testing interview questions.**

Answer (score 4):

As an interviewer, getting one of the text book replies will mainly loose point for the candidate. The correct answer should be something along the lines of "it depends".

Non standardize definitions change from company to company and from team to team, even the first two answers from ashu and log_file are inconsistent with each other.

Comment: Exactly. Such question should be an invitation to show experience: describe process used in previous position(s), and ask how it differs to the process in the company you are interviewing in, what changes company plans to do to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between Pilot and Beta Testing :

- Pilot testing involves having a group of end users try the system prior to its full deployment in order to give feedback on its performance. It is done by group of users who try to test the system prior its full deployment to provide the feedback about the quality.
- Beta testing is testing of the product in the user environment. It is done at the client side and all end users use the system and see whether the system is working as per their given requirements. This is done after pilot testing is successful and the defects found in case of pilot testing are fixed.

From the definitions, its is evident that beta testing comes at last in development cycle; whereas pilot testing takes place before deployment of the system. Also, beta testing takes place in real time user environment and pilot testing in development environment. A selected group of users do pilot testing whereas beta testing is carried by all users.

- Limited users use the product in pilot testing, where as real data does not input and is installed at the end customer to validate once the product is ready for the production in beta testing.

Answer (score 0):

Pilot testing involves having a group of users try the system prior to its full deployment in order to give feedback on its performance.

Beta testing is testing of the product in the user environment.

Also, beta testing takes place in real time user environment and pilot testing in development environment. A selected group of users do pilot testing whereas beta testing is carried by all users.

Comment: That means Pilot testing in done at Developers site. end users come to the developer company for testing?

Comment: a beta is an external work in progress and the pilot represents the final pre-release test

Answer (score 0):

Pilot Testing answers to the question: does this new product/service have a potential market? Pilot testing allows people involved in marketing and business strategies to take decisions for investments. When we do pilot testing the software is just a bit more than a prototype.

Beta Testing answers to the questions: Does the product/service fulfill the customers’ requirements or expected behaviors? Beta testing could help companies to confirm if a product is ready for the distribution.

Honestly it's not a common question for a job interview, anyhow I hope you have even received more technical questions to show your competencies.

Answer (score 0):

1.Pilot testing involves having a group of end users try the system prior to its full deployment in order to give feedback on its performance.

2.Beta testing is testing of the product in the user environment.

3.Its is evident that beta testing comes at last in development cycle; whereas pilot testing takes place before deployment of the system. Also, beta testing takes place in the real-time user environment and pilot testing in the development environment. A selected group of users does pilot testing whereas beta testing is carried by all users.